# SQL find in Table A where not in Query B

Tags: sql

I want to find all companies in Table A which do not have any 'Active' locations in Table B. Active means an Active flag set to true.

Table A 
ID : integer
CustomerName : string
Active : boolean

Table B
ID : integer
LocationName : string
TABLEA_ID : integer
Active : boolean

Some of the records in Table B have active and non active locations for the same customer. I want to know which customers in Table A do not have any active locations in Table B.

Comment: What database platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard types of query.  Here is the `left join` approach:

```
select a.*
from a left join
     b
     on b.tablea_id = a.id and b.active = true
where b.id is null;
```

The exact syntax for `b.active = true` may vary among databases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `JOIN` between the tables like

```
select t1.id,t1.CustomerName, t2.LocationName
from tablea t1 join tableb t2 on t1.ID = t2.TABLEA_ID
where t2.Active = false;
```